# OpenGL - Create a grid of cubes

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

[image][image]I want to create a grid in C++ with OpenGL with glut implementation, using the cube i've already made. The grid should be 15x15 . Tried with for loops but can't seem to find an efficient way to do it , writing as little code as possible using loops . Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>     // openGL header
#include <GL/glu.h>   // glut header
#include <GL/glut.h>   // glut header




void init()
{       //for 3d lighting
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    GLint viewport[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    double aspect = (double)viewport[2] / (double)viewport[3];
    gluPerspective(60, aspect, 1, 100);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // move back a bit
    glTranslatef( 0, 0, -35 );


    float e=0,f=0;


    for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++) {      
            glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(0.0f+e,0.0f+f,0.0f); //right and up
                glRotatef(20.0f,1.0f,-2.0f,0.0f); //looking 3d
                    glColor3ub(245, 245, 220); //Beige
                    glutSolidCube(2.25);
                glPopMatrix();

            /*glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(0.0f-e,0.0f-f,0.0f); //
                glRotatef(20.0f,1.0f,-2.0f,0.0f); //looking 3d
                    glColor3ub(245, 245, 220); //Beige
                    glutSolidCube(2.25);
                glPopMatrix();*/


                f=+-2.63;
            }
            f=0;
            e+=2.63;
        }

    /*e=0;
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f+e,0.0f);
            glRotatef(20.0f,1.0f,-2.0f,0.0f); //looking 3d
                glColor3ub(245, 245, 0); //Beige
                glutSolidCube(2.2);
            glPopMatrix();

            e+=2.63;
        }*/

    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void reshape(GLsizei width, GLsizei height) { 

    // GLsizei for non-negative integer // Compute aspect ratio of the new window

    if (height == 0) height = 1; // To prevent divide by 0 
    GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height; // Set the viewport to cover the new window 
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height); // Set the aspect ratio of the clipping volume                 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // To operate on the Projection matrix 
    glLoadIdentity(); // Reset // Enable perspective projection with fovy, aspect, zNear and zFar 
    gluPerspective(45.0f, aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f); 

} 

void timer(int extra)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(16, timer, 0);
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitWindowSize(600,600);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE| GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
        glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE); //anti-alliasing  
        glutCreateWindow("CUBES");

     glutDisplayFunc(display);
     glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
     glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);

     init();

     glutMainLoop();
     return 0;
}
```

The idea is creating the cube at the centre and duplicating in order to make the desirable 15x15 grid.

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Also, what are you seeing so far?

Comment: there isn't one , i just can't fill all the grid efficiently . In the for loop i have i fill the 7 cubes right of the centre , and another seven below of them. I whish to find an efficient way to duplicate the central cube and make the 15x15 grid

Comment: update it with current output

Comment: yes nested loop is the solution, but can't seem to be able to implement it in the right way

Comment: "right way" and "efficient way" could mean 2 different things here. Do you just want them centered in the view? You are already doing it efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be your problem,

```
f=+-2.63;  

should be

f += -2.63;
```

right?

Comment: And `f` needs to start at from the left: `f= -2.63 * (8/2)` Where `8` is from the iteration count

Comment: thanks for all the input . Works fine , just a remark i would wish they all would look the same . I think cause of translation they also rotate so for example top left cubes don't look like right bottom . Is there any way of looking all similar , preferably like the central cube. I'll update with a picture to show what i mean.

Comment: It would be very hard and time consuming to adjust the transformation for each of the cube to make them appear similar through perspective projection.  What you probably want is to use an orthographic projection (gluOrtho2d or something like that) instead, it will give you a consistence look but flat, as the projection flatten your scene.  It's all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: ive been trying with glOrtho(-50.0, 50.0, -50.0, 50.0, -1.0, 1.0) . Seem that I can get 3d viewing but looks a bit odd , idk maybe with combination of the lights. Anyway I think the 3d look and all cubes looking the same can be achieved with gluOrtho and the right lights , but still cant seem to find the correct way to implement that

Comment: Your glOrtho setting is off, it's what causing some of the distortion you're seeing.  You want to set it to match your screen size, something like glOrtho(0.0f, 600.0f, 600.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); for now.  This is a big topic in 3D graphic, I think it's best to look further into 3D transformation if you want to gain a deeper understanding on how a 3D coordinates get transform and eventually end up as a bunch of pixels on screen.  I don't have any resources to point you to at the moment, but if you search for "3D transformation" it should get you to the information you're looking for.